# Python urllib urllib2 keeping sessions

Tags: python, download, urllib2, urllib

Iam trying to find a way how to keep the cookie sessions while performing the urllib command to download files.
Here what I have so far.

```
            session.get(url, data=login_data, verify=False)

            f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            data = f.read()
            with open('C:/Files/filename.docx', "wb") as code:
                code.write(data)
```

url is URL
data are login details username and password

So when I run this, no success.

Does anyone have experience with that?

Comment: You need to install a cookie manager to the opener.

Comment: Might be worth looking into requests to make your life simpler: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ Also if you're sending data then you would need a post request, not a get request.

Comment: Looking at your code again, the syntax for `session.get()` looks almost identical to requests already. Are you sure you're not using that library? Also you're downloading a file from your `C:/` drive which is a local file, so what are you logging into?

Comment: I am loggin with `code` with session() as session:
    """ Login """
    session.post('my url with login form', data=login_data, verify=False) `code`
And then I call the login with <code> session.get </code>

Comment: It works when I just read the names of the files, but not if I want to download them